# To remove formatting in SSRS Excel report

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have SSRS reports deployed in a server .I have options to export report both in pdf and excel format.My problem is the excel equivalent of the report that is generated is looking as if the pdf report is copied and pasted where borders between cells are not displaying,each group data is getting displayed in separate sheets,the requirement is that all groupings must get populated one below the other.These things can make any analyst very difficult to work with such kind of excel file.

Is there any way using which i can remove such formatting in exported excel report and it looks like a normal spreadsheet report.

Comment: What version of SSRS?  Either way, no.  You can remove all of the formatting in the report such that it's just a grid and then it will export better.  So then, you'll have one report for review and one for exporting / subscriptions.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  SSRS 2005's export to Excel is usually pretty ugly.  Please do as I suggested in the other comment.  There's no way to control the export formatting directly.  Alternatively, export at CSV and import in Excel.